# install ubuntu 13.10 without losing data on d rive

Tags: partitioning, windows-xp

i have 2 partition on my hdd one is having windows xp and other is having my personal data ( D ) i want to install ubuntu in d drive without loosing my personal data. i also have 10 gb free space on it.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant install ubuntu 13.10 on a drive with data in it. Earlier in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, wubi(windows ubuntu installer) does install in a drive as it makes a folder name ubuntu inside the d drive. but it get discontinued after that. During installation, you must format the drive as ext4 or ext3 to install it.

There is other way, you can shrink your d drive to make another drive which can be used to install ubuntu. But beware it can damage the partitions, as it might be a chance your d drive is a logical partition. So see your partition from the manage storage in windows before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new ntfs partition from the 10 gb free space.
- Copy all the personal datas from D drive to the newly created ntfs partition.
- Boot Ubuntu live disk,choose something else option and then format D drive to ext4 filesystem.After that install Ubuntu on the formatted D drive.

Please note,on Ubuntu installation it doesn't mention the drives as D or C.So you have to find the partitions according to their sizes.